# Have and =Have been

Tags: difference, perfect-constructions

What is difference between the two sentence below?

> 1. I have delivered the file yesterday
> 2. I have **been** delivered the file yesterday

Comment: Why would you want to use either when the action was clearly completed in the past?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should not use "yesterday" with the present perfect. Either use the perfect "I have delivered the file (already)." or the past tense "I delivered the file yesterday".

To "be delivered" is a passive form. It is rather odd, but I would understand "I have been delivered the file" as an odd way of saying "Someone has delivered me the file" or equivalently "I have received the file"

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are incorrect.

"I have delivered the file yesterday"

Should be: *I delivered the file yesterday*

or *I had delivered the file yesterday* - if the context requires the past perfect tense.

"I have been delivered the file yesterday"

Should be: *The file was delivered to me yesterday* or *I received the file yesterday*

or *I had received the file yesterday* - if the context requires the past perfect tense.

Be careful not to say *I was delivered of the file yesterday* because that would mean you gave birth to the file.